# Как сделать блок, часть которого будет переноситься на другую строку? (Кастомный text-decoration)

Tags: html, css

В попытке создать кастомный `text-decoration "dashed"`, столкнулся с проблемой.
Если подчеркнутый текст будет перенесен на другую строку (уменьшите в примере ширину фрейма с результатом), подчеркивание пропадает.

Как понял, проблема в том, что блок не может перенестись на другую строку вместе с текстом.

Есть ли возможность создать блок, часть которого переносилась бы на следующую строку если не помещается полностью на текущей?

Если это не возможно, какие способы сделать своё подчеркивание знаете вы?

https://jsfiddle.net/4c5aqpjk/1/

```css
.underline {
  position: relative;
}
.underline:after {
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    content: '';
    bottom: -.1em;
    left: .1em;
    right: .1em;
    border-top: 1px dashed;
}
```

```html
<span class="underline">длинный текст</span>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.underline {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
Обыкновенный <span class="underline">длинный текст Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime impedit eveniet commodi dolorem laborum modi provident blanditiis odit ipsa quasi rerum nisi odio dolores tempore perferendis deleniti, explicabo atque delectus quo veritatis neque aut! Magni nam modi praesentium fugiat minus quas pariatur culpa, tempora quae sapiente quos mollitia, dolorum numquam possimus omnis ipsa. Dolor officia dolore aut debitis officiis enim, corporis hic non reiciendis eveniet quasi atque, asperiores. Iusto nesciunt aperiam possimus, vero impedit quasi deleniti iste cum voluptate sit!</span>
```

```css
.underline {
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed;
}
```

```html
Обыкновенный <u class="underline">длинный текст Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Maxime impedit eveniet commodi dolorem laborum modi provident blanditiis odit ipsa quasi rerum nisi odio dolores tempore perferendis deleniti, explicabo atque delectus quo veritatis neque aut! Magni nam modi praesentium fugiat minus quas pariatur culpa, tempora quae sapiente quos mollitia, dolorum numquam possimus omnis ipsa. Dolor officia dolore aut debitis officiis enim, corporis hic non reiciendis eveniet quasi atque, asperiores. Iusto nesciunt aperiam possimus, vero impedit quasi deleniti iste cum voluptate sit!</u>
```

Comment: А теперь отодвиньте полосу подчеркивания от текста на 5px

Comment: padding-bottom: 5px

Comment: Ну не знаю, "Использование этого тега осуждается спецификацией HTML, валидный код получается только при использовании переходного <!DOCTYPE>."

Comment: Если больше вариантов никто не предложит - буду использовать этот и делать интернет хуже, не следуя спецификациям

Comment: Добавил пример с padding и span

Comment: Причем тут спецификация, используйте тот тег, который вас устраивает, но реализуйте бордер без помощи псевдоэлементов, а сразу на inline элементе.

Comment: @l2banners не знаю почему сам не додумался, спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

Можно сделать через `background-image`, тогда вы можете менять вид пунктирной линии, ее размер, цвет:

```css
.dashed {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, blue 75%, transparent 75%);
  background-position: 0 1em;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 10px 1px;
}
```

```html
<span class="dashed">Ваш очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень очень длинный текст</span>
```